# Breadcrumbs on Blog Post (orchard cms)

Tags: menu, navigation, widget, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have an Orchard site that has 3 blogs. (version 1.6)

Blogs are in navigation

I have put a menu on top (default) one on content aside (start level 2, 1 level to display) and one more on top set as breadcrumb...

On all pages these menus are correct...

If I go to blog main page all is ok.

When I go to a blog post both right and breadcrumb menu loose the "focus" on the blog and show all first level menu item (the breadcrumb) or all the level 2 items (the aside menu)

How I can fix that?

I understand that menu widget loses focus because the whole url is not on navigation.

Is there any workaround to let know to menu that it should just treat the blog post as the blog main page instead of post url itself (a sort of canonical reference url)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried separating your breadcrumbs into separate navigation menu's and separate navigation widgets into their own layers?

ie.

Layer name: Not Blogs
Match: not url(~/blog1*) and not url(~/blog2*) and not url(~/blog3*)
Widgets to include: Breadcrumbs for pages

Layer name: Not Blog1
Match: url(~/blog1*)
Widgets to include: Breadcrumbs for Blog1

Layer name: Not Blog
Match: url(~/blog2*)
Widgets to include: Breadcrumbs for Blog2

Layer name: Not Blog3
Match: url(~/blog3*)
Widgets to include: Breadcrumbs for Blog3

Comment: It seems a nice idea... I will try and I will let you know how it worked. Thanks...

Comment: Happy to hear! Good luck with your project.